# Reading Outlook PidNameContentType with Redemption.MAPIUtils.HrGetOneProp

Tags: outlook-redemption

I'm using **Redemption.MAPIUtils** to read the content of the extended property **PidNameContentType** in an
**Outlook 2016 Email** object.

This is my code:

```
Redemption.MAPIUtils MAPIUtils_l = new Redemption.MAPIUtils();
int ContentTypeTag_l = unchecked((int)0x8063001F);  
string Content_l;
Content_l = MAPIUtils_l.HrGetOneProp(NewMail_l.MAPIOBJECT, ContentTypeTag_l);
```

With this code I read the same content as OutlookSpy.
[OutlookSpy_Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVscu.png)

If I run the code in a **Outlook 365** environment, the content is always empty.
But OutlookSpy does show me exactly the same information.

What in my code do I have to change to read the value of PIDNameContentType in Outlook 365?

many regards
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hardcoding a named property tag (`0x8063001F`) - it will only be valid in the mailbox the screenshot comes from from. You need to call `MAPIUtils_l.GetIdsFromNames` passing the GUID and the string id, "or" the returned value with `0x001F` (`PT_UNICODE`), and only then use that tag to call `HrGetOneProp`.

Or you can use the DASL property name (OutlookSpy shows it) abd pass it to `RDOMail.Fields[]` in Redemption or `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetPropert`y in OOM.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, thank you for the quick support. I was able to read the property value via RDOMail.Fields.

Comment: @Andreas - if the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!